# What is difference between deny user on database and each table

Tags: sql-server

I find the scripts to deny the specific user to select from web as below. Is it same result?

Script #1:

```
USE [DB]
GO

EXEC sp_msforeachtable "DENY SELECT ON ? TO [UserA]
GO
```

Script #2:

```
USE [DB]
GO

DENY SELECT TO [UserA]
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The first query applies the `DENY SELECT` on all the tables present in `DB` at execution time. Any tables added in the future will *not* have this explicit `DENY SELECT` permission applied to this user.

The second query is database-wide denial of the `SELECT` privilege, which would restrict this operation for this user for all current and future tables in `DB`.

(As a side note, it’s probably not a good idea to leverage undocumented stored procedures in SQL Server - they are likely undocumented for a reason, and can be removed or changed at any time without notice and break any workflows that rely on them.)